# Flutter app size huge, how to reduce for ios

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios-build

#issue: ios app size going big.
We build An app For ios and android with flutter.  For android this app size left 32 MB but when we upload the  same app to appstore its size increased  to 80 MB. Why?  Can i get any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, launching your app with flutter run, or by clicking the Play button in your IDE generates a debug build of the Flutter app. The app size of a debug build is large due to the debugging overhead that allows for hot reload and source-level debugging. As such, it is not representative of a production app end users download.

Breaking down the size
Starting in Flutter version 1.22 and DevTools version 0.9.1, a size analysis tool is included to help developers understand the breakdown of the release build of their application.

```
flutter build ios --analyze-size
```

Reducing app size
When building a release version of your app, consider using the --split-debug-info tag. This tag can dramatically reduce code size. F
Some of the other things you can do to make your app smaller are:

Remove unused resources
Minimize resource imported from libraries
Compress PNG and JPEG files

For more info [check this](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size)

Answer (score -2):

Try with this info tag

```
flutter build apk --obfuscate --split-debug-info=build/app/outputs/symbols
```

Comment: this is for the iOS not android